# Selecting an ID based on hierarchical criteria

Tags: r, dataset, conditional-statements

Helo there. I have a group of patients diagnosed with a certain disease (but with different criteria) at different dates, as follows:

```r
ID1 = c(12,14,56)
Date_ID1 = c(20160209,20120101, 20170227)
Criteria_1 = c("B","C","A")

ID2 = c(NA,43,22)
Date_ID2 = c(NA,20160710,20170227)
Criteria_2 = c(NA,"B","B")

ID3 = c(96,41,123)
Date_ID3 = c(20170227,20120101,20160601)
Criteria_3 = c("A","B","A") 

test = data.frame(ID1, Criteria_1,Date_ID1,ID2, Criteria_2,Date_ID2,ID3,Criteria_3,Date_ID3)
```

Each row represent the same patient, a new ID ascribed at every exam.
What I need is to select one ID per row based on a hierarchical criteria (A>B>C); in case of ties, the select ID should correspond to the earliest date of that diagnosis. The output is expected to look like this:

```r
cbind(test,data.frame(Selected_ID = c(96,41,123)) )
```

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Are there always three criteria?

Comment: Actually there are four of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding a row ID to your `test`.

```
testR = data.frame(ID1, Criteria_1,Date_ID1,ID2 ,Criteria_2,Date_ID2,ID3,Criteria_3,Date_ID3) %>% 
  rowid_to_column("ROW")


library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
```

`pivot_longer` three ways.  (I think I could have done this in one fell swoop, but I
find this easier to understand.  I'm breaking this pipeline into individual chunks so you can evaluate them separately and see what's going on.  But I'm not printing the intermediate results; makes posts too long

```
piv3 <- testR %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Criteria"),
               names_to = "Criteria_L",
               values_to = "CritLetter")  %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Date"),
               names_to = "Date_L",
               values_to = "Date") %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("ID"),
               names_to = "ID_L",
               values_to = "ID") 


clnPiv <- piv3 %>% 
  filter(!is.na(ID)) %>% 
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(matches("_L")), ~ str_sub(., -1)) %>% 
  filter(Criteria_L == Date_L & Date_L == ID_L)
```

I will print out clnPiv , tho

```
# A tibble: 8 x 7
    ROW Criteria_L CritLetter Date_L Date       ID_L     ID
  <int> <chr>      <fct>      <chr>  <date>     <chr> <dbl>
1     1 1          B          1      2016-02-09 1        12
2     1 3          A          3      2017-02-27 3        96
3     2 1          C          1      2012-01-01 1        14
4     2 2          B          2      2016-07-10 2        43
5     2 3          B          3      2012-01-01 3        41
6     3 1          A          1      2017-02-27 1        56
7     3 2          B          2      2017-02-27 2        22
8     3 3          A          3      2016-06-01 3       123


selexId <- clnPiv %>% 
  group_by(ROW) %>% 
  arrange(CritLetter, Date) %>% 
  summarise(SelectedID = first(ID))

testR %>% 
  left_join(selexId, by = "ROW")


  ROW ID1 Criteria_1 Date_ID1 ID2 Criteria_2 Date_ID2 ID3 Criteria_3 Date_ID3 SelectedID
1   1  12          B 20160209  NA       <NA>       NA  96          A 20170227         96
2   2  14          C 20120101  43          B 20160710  41          B 20120101         41
3   3  56          A 20170227  22          B 20170227 123          A 20160601        123
```

Comment: I was stuck in a for loop/if else solution. Thanks.

Comment: I know you're new; not long ago I was too.  A little StackOverlfow etiquette: if somebody's answered a question for you, #ACCEPT# their answer.  You do that by clicking the gray checkmark (upper left of the post) and turning it green.  You can also upvote a post with the arrows above the check. It awards 15 reputation pts for an ACCEPT, another 10 for an upvote.  AND, you can upvote comments. E.g., if someone's comments helped you understand something, you should upvote them too.  That awards 2 pt.  ALSO, _you_ get 2 pts for accepting an answer.